# Trying to define a method within a method within a class

Tags: ruby, class, methods, specifications

I'm trying to get a spec to pass and I'm receiving an error, "undefined method `first_word' for "Inferno":String"

I have defined the 'first_word' method, it is within the class method 'title'. I'm having trouble determining how I can call this 'first_word' method on a string within the class method 'title'.

the spec:

describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title = "inferno"
      @book.title.should == "Inferno"
    end

```
it 'should capitalize every word' do
  @book.title = "stuart little"
  @book.title.should == "Stuart Little"
end

describe 'should capitalize every word except...' do
  describe 'articles' do
    specify 'the' do
      @book.title = "alexander the great"
      @book.title.should == "Alexander the Great"
    end

    specify 'a' do
      @book.title = "to kill a mockingbird"
      @book.title.should == "To Kill a Mockingbird"
    end

    specify 'an' do
      @book.title = "to eat an apple a day"
      @book.title.should == "To Eat an Apple a Day"
    end
  end

  specify 'conjunctions' do
    @book.title = "war and peace"
    @book.title.should == "War and Peace"
  end

  specify 'prepositions' do
    @book.title = "love in the time of cholera"
    @book.title.should == "Love in the Time of Cholera"
  end
end

describe 'should always capitalize...' do
  specify 'I' do
    @book.title = "what i wish i knew when i was 20"
    @book.title.should == "What I Wish I Knew When I Was 20"
  end

  specify 'the first word' do
    @book.title = "the man in the iron mask"
    @book.title.should == "The Man in the Iron Mask"
  end
end
```

my code:

```
    class Book
attr_accessor :title
def initialize
  @title
end
def title=(str)
  def first_word
    self[0,1].capitalize + self[1,-1]
  end
  cap_except = ["over","and","of","a","to","the","an","or","but","if","else","in"]
  str = str.split.map {|w| cap_except.include?(w) ? w : w.capitalize}.join(" ").first_word
  @title = str
end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `first_word` *on* a string, similar to `"foo".length`.

You haven't defined `first_word` on the `String` class.

You have defined a method that you call *with* a string, e.g., `first_word("foo")`.

Unrelated, but *why* are you trying to nest method definitions like this?

Comment: In teaching/learning on my own, I'm not sure which would be the best way of trying to get my desired result. So to answer your question of why, the honest answer is I'm not sure. I'm trying to create a method which can be called on a string which will allow me to capitalize the first letter of a string and not change the rest of the string and do this within the class I've created.

Comment: Thank you for adding context to this Dave. By creating another class String and defining the method in there I was able to call it on a string